# How can I run release build of my Flutter app on Simulator

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

I need to take screenshots of my Flutter application across various devices.  Since I do not have a variety of physical devices, I need to use the Simulator.  However, I cannot figure out how to run my app in non-debug mode -- I always see the "Debug" banner in the top right corner.  **How can I run a *Release* build in the iOS Simulator?**

When I try: `flutter run --release`, it says, "**Release mode is not supported for emulators.**"

When I try: `flutter install`, it says:

```
[ +108 ms] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
                    Failed to install the requested application
                    An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
                    Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
[  +12 ms] "flutter install" took 4,601ms.
Install failed
```

Alternatively, can I run a debug build without showing the Debug banner?

Comment: if you want different screen sizes, you will find this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview) extremely useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You won't be able to run release mode on simulator as it only runs on actual device.

However you can remove the debug banner by passing `debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false` in your `MaterialApp()`

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
  home:...
)
```

Answer (score 9):

The command `flutter run --release` compiles to release mode.

To remove "debug banner" you can use debugShowCheckedModeBanner property of MaterialApp() widget. If you set this property to false , banner will be disappeared.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            home: HomePage(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: From Review: Please do not provide source code in form of an image, please always post it text.

Answer (score 6):

**No, You can't run ios release build on Simulator.** You need a actual device to run release build.

If you want to remove the debug banner from your app,

Add this line in your `MaterialApp`

```
debugShowCheckedModeBanner:false,
```

To run release build on android devices

```
flutter run --release
```

To get release build on your storage

```
flutter build apk --release
```

This will generate a release build, If you want to get a normal build run below command

```
flutter run
```

If you want to get ios build you should run this command ( you can't run this command on Windows and LINUX computers, You need a MAC system for get ios build )

```
flutter build ios
```

I hope this will help someone who new to flutter

Answer (score -1):

1. run `flutter clean`
2. enable `android:debuggable="true"` in manifest
3. `flutter build --release`

it works for me in emulator pixel 3 and real device

Comment: This might work on Android, but OP asked about running on an iOS simulator.

Answer (score -1):

The command `flutter run --release` compiles to release mode.

check the [official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes) for Flutter's build modes

Answer (score -1):

Running `flutter run --release` worked for me even on the emulator and also I received FCM notification.